# JPA createQuery where condition does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am trying to use JPA to fetch records from database. However I am able to insert records indatabse and even get all the records using createQuery method of class EntityManager.

But in below case I am not getting why the condition in where clause is not working.

Please help me figure it out.

POJO class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "frameworks_filter")
public class FilteredFrameworksDbStructure {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "regular_name")
    private String regularName;
    
    @Column(name = "component_name")
    private String componentName;
    
    @Column(name = "component_owner")
    private String componentOwner;
    
    @Column(name = "frameworks")
    private String frameworks;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getRegularName() {
        return regularName;
    }
    public void setRegularName(String regularName) {
        this.regularName = regularName;
    }
    public String getComponentName() {
        return componentName;
    }
    public void setComponentName(String componentName) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
    }
    public String getComponentOwner() {
        return componentOwner;
    }
    public void setComponentOwner(String componentOwner) {
        this.componentOwner = componentOwner;
    }
    public String getFrameworks() {
        return frameworks;
    }
    public void setFrameworks(String frameworks) {
        this.frameworks = frameworks;
    }
}
```

DAO class method:

```
public List<FilteredFrameworksDbStructure> getFilteredFrameworks(String regularName) {

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        
        List<FilteredFrameworksDbStructure> filteredFrameworksDbStructureList = entityManager
                .createQuery("from FilteredFrameworksDbStructure F where F.regularName = :regular", FilteredFrameworksDbStructure.class)
                .setParameter("regular", regularName)
                .getResultList();
        

        return filteredFrameworksDbStructureList;
    }
```

Issue : Condition in where clause does not work. It simply fetch all the records irrespective of the regularName provided.

Regards,
Parag Vinchurkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` to fetch your results? Check out this tutorial [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-spring-data-jpa) and [here](https://www.springboottutorial.com/introduction-to-jpa-with-spring-boot-data-jpa) on how to use them.

And you can use your where clause. Please see below the example repository you can use to obtain the same results as the `entityManager`

```
public interface FilteredFrameworksDbStructureRepo extends JpaRepository<FilteredFrameworksDbStructure , Integer>{

    List<FilteredFrameworksDbStructure> findAllByRegularName(String regularName)
}
```

Please note that you will have to change your `id` member variable  from `int` to `Integer`